# SQL Error rows handling dynamic content issue

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am encountering difficulties while attempting to configure dynamic content within a Synapse Dataflow to selectively apply error handling strategies based on the workspace environment. Im trying to utilize the "Stop on first error" option (which is the default setting) when operating within a production environment, and switch to "Continue on error" for development workspaces. Although the "Error row handling" dropdown menu is meant to support for dynamic content,The system appears to misconstrue the dynamic content as a column reference, as illustrated in Figure 2.

The logic intended to dictate the error handling strategy is as follows:

```
case($ws == 'dev', allErrors, stopOnFirstError)
```

However, when `allErrors` is input as dynamic content and interpreted as a string, the dataflow execution halts due to an error concerning the transaction commit type. The error message received is as follows:

```json
{
  "message": "Job failed due to reason: com.microsoft.dataflow.Issues: DF-SRC-004 - 'transactionCommit' (Configure transactions for data writes affecting visibility of data changes. Values: batch = multiple smaller transactions, single = single transaction) should be one of the allowed values single, batch - EXE-0001, Dataflow cannot be analyzed as a graph,
selectDims sink(
) ~> sinkDimReturnStatus,[564 737]. Details:",
  "failureType": "UserError",
  "target": "GO_Dims",
  "errorCode": "DFExecutorUserError"
}
```

Fig 1: Synapse error row dropdown

[image]

Fig 2: Error within Dynamic Content

[image]

I am seeking insights on how to correctly implement dynamic content for error row handling within a Synapse Dataflow. How can I ensure that dynamic content is not misinterpreted as a column and that the appropriate error handling strategy is applied based on the workspace environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

You will get the above error when you gave a string value other than `Single` and `batch` for the **Transaction Commit** dynamic content in the **Errors** of the sink.

To overcome the error and to achieve your requirement, use the **Error row handling** like below.

[image]

Give the expression `case($ws == 'dev', 'allErrors', 'stopOnFirstError')` to the **Error row handling** dynamic expression and use any of the `Single` or `batch` option for the **Transaction Commit** from the drop down.

**This is my input data:**

```
Id,Chec
1,Starc
3,Rakesh
5,Virat
6,ABD
7,Ryan Harris
8,Kieswetter
```

Here, I have set the data type as `varchar(5)` for the column `Chec` in the SQL target table. That means the error rows are the rows which have the length more than 5 for the column `Chec`. I have taken the dataflow parameter `$ws` as same as yours.

**Results when passing dataflow parameter value as `'dev'` from pipeline:**

The dataflow will succeed and you can see only the required rows got copied to the target table.

[image]

**Error rows file:**

[image]

**Dataflow got failed as expected when given value other than `'dev'`for the parameter:**

[image]